# How to make malicious usernames unfunctional in chats and MySQL DB

Tags: php, javascript-injection

I want to convert all the malicious characters to not be malicious for all people, when used in node.js server. But do not ruin the name completely. The *'s look really bad, can I convert them to make them able to use as username, but not malicious/unfuctional?

Example: `alert("Test");` username will show alert for ALL people who are connected to the chatroom on socket.io.

Right now im using:

```
$name = str_replace("script", "*", $name);
$name = str_replace("/", "*", $name);
$name = str_replace("<", "*", $name);
$name = str_replace(">", "*", $name);
$name = str_replace("body", "*", $name);
$name = str_replace("onload", "*", $name);
$name = str_replace("alert", "*", $name);
$name = str_replace(")", "*", $name);
$name = str_replace("(", "*", $name);
$name = str_replace("'", "*", $name);
```

Comment: There are other huge mistakes in your code if a string someone writes can cause an actual alert

Comment: Since I'm using login API, I cannot regulate usernames, I need to use them and fix them and store them into DB.

Comment: The problem isn't with regulating user names, it's with those usernames being injected into the page where they run in an uncontrolled fashion. `alert('Test')` as a username should **never** be able to run JS code.

Comment: A better strategy is to add a set of "whitelist" rules.  If you try to prevent all of the bad things, you will be in a constant game of whack-a-mole struggling to stay one step ahead of the bad guys.  That will suck, so just write the rules for what you are willing to allow, and go from there.

Comment: have you tried using htmlentities its a good handy tool, and replacing < > / with asterisks is quite not nice, you might wanna replace it with a blank space. if you're fine with str_replace function... Still not a bad idea